# Prevent stealing HTML5 video in the browser?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking for a way to securely deliver video to mobile devices. There are two options:

1. **HLS in  tag**. This works very nicely for iOS and supports adaptive bitrate, perfect for mobile. However, is seems to only work well on iOS. There seems to be only fragmented support for it on Android. I've read that Android has officially supported it since 3.0, but on all the android devices I've tested (>3.0), HLS hasn't played back on the browser.
2. **Progressive download in  tag**. This will work on iOS and Android devices fine, but the concern is that since it's just a progressive download of the video, that the user find a way to just grab that video once the browser has finished downloading it. This may be more difficult on iOS, but I'm sure it's not that hard to figure out where the browser stored the video download in a tmp folder somewhere.

Either method I'd say can be protected from deeplinking by using an expiring token approach, where the token is generated serverside with a secret key that only the content server knows about. The video request would only be valid for 5 or 10 minutes, would would kill of deeplinking.

Is anyone aware of any way around these issues? Even if I was able to prevent deeplinking, the user could still get the video itself and re-distribute. Perhaps it's just not possible?

Thanks

Comment: If people *really* want to, they can always steal your video, regardless of what you do...

Comment: you are sending the content to the client. Game over.

Answer (score 5):

**Rule #1 of the internet:**

If you don't want someone stealing it, don't put it online.

Welcome to the circumvention arms race. Brought to you by [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do to stop someone who really wants to pirate your video.  There are various measures, like those you mention, that make it more difficult, but someone who really wants to copy it could find a way to capture it from memory, or even just point a camera at the screen and record the playback of the video.

It's the same way you protect your car.  You install a steering lock, an alarm and an engine immobiliser, and then someone comes alongs and pulls the car onto a flat-bed truck and drives away with it.

Bottom line - you can't stop a determined thief, but you can make theft more difficult so that you're not the most attractive target.

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading the above I could easily get pass all these techniques pretty quickly.

For a project I can't describe too much because of nda, we created our own protocol based on a well known encryption method can't mention that either , military grade)  , encoded packets on the server to the protocol, and decoded on the device.
unfortunately this isn't perfect either because a lot of mobile apps can be re-versed engineered and once you get the key game over, very easy on android, of course you could periodically recycle the key, in which case even if they decompiled the android app and got the key it wouldn't work very long.

This is a lot of work and can't be implemented with html5 or hLS or event rtsp.

It also requires a custom server application that takes the video stream re-transmits it with the custom protocol.

On the other hand the protocol was transport agnostic, which meant we could use a variety of transports, tcp, IAP and bluetooth. Also would work on all mobile / desktop platforms.

The other little requirement, is couldn't use a browser, have to be a custom app.